# create a file called hello.txt that contains the word "hello world"?

Tags: linux

question is as bellow:-

create a file called hello.txt that contains the words "hello world",. can you use "cp" using "terminal" as the source file to achieve the same effect?

i already create a text file and name as hello.txt. then i type a command in linux terminal asbellow:-

cp hello.txt /home/tobenrry

but it is error and cannot get the output.
i try many command already for creating this. but it is also not work. may i knows what the the command for the question?

Answer (score 1):

On Linux the current terminal is identified by the device /dev/tty, so you can do:

```
cp /dev/tty hello.txt
```

That's what the question is asking for.

Comment: After this you can enter your preferred input, "hello world" in your case. To finish the file, press ctrl+D

Comment: On Ubuntu 13.10: `cp: cannot create special file ‘hello.txt’: Operation not permitted`. This is in my home directory.

Comment: @Tony I'm guessing this behaviour is caused by a bash alias. Try using `/bin/cp` to avoid the alias.

Comment: @Robin Green: Good catch. I aliased cp to "cp -r" because I couldn't envision a time when I wouldn't want copies to be recursive. :) The operation works with /bin/cp. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

copy from stdin to file:

```
 cp /dev/stdin $HOME/test.txt
 cat > $HOME/test.txt

 cat /dev/tty > test.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

say terminal = /dev/tty

type the following commands:

cat >terminal

"enter the txt here say "hello world" "
ctrl+D

cp terminal destinationfilename